# How to identify/Search '-' in a string in Apache phoenix?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I would like to identify/Search  "-" (hyphen) in a string using Apache Phoenix.
I need to select all the records which contain "-" (hyphen) in it.
For example, string === abcda-1.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * from foo where s_value like '%-%';
```

The % character is a regex character.
You can see more operators and examples at [phoenix documentation](http://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#condition).